# can my child fly to Pakistan with me with proof he has been approved. My child is dependent on me he is 18 months

Tags: pakistani-citizens, pakistan

I have received approval for my child’s nadra card. It has gone for printing however if I do not receive it back by the time we fly out can my child still go with me with proof he has been approved. My child is dependent on me he is 18 months

Comment: @mlc since the child is younger than 2 years, I expect that is is very unlikely indeed that he has an expired NICOP or POC card.  (It seems that NADRA is the government body that issues the NICOP card.)

Comment: @phoog the question is poorly titled but there's a child in it who has no card and the answers address it